# How to replace a sentence with special chars?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm creating a script with automates openvpn installation on a server, one of the things i need to do it to replace a line in a file:

```
sed -i 's/export KEY_CONFIG='$EASY_RSA/whichopensslcnf $EASY_RSA'/export KEY_CONFIG=/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/openssl-1.0.0.cnf/g' /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/vars
```

I know there's some escaping needed to be done here but I'm not sure which keys are ones need escaping. Can you please assist?

This is the sentence from the `vars` file:

```
# This variable should point to
# the openssl.cnf file included
# with easy-rsa.
export KEY_CONFIG=`$EASY_RSA/whichopensslcnf $EASY_RSA`

# Edit this variable to point to
```

I want to replace the uncommented line with:
`export KEY_CONFIG=/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/openssl-1.0.0.cnf` (as is)

Comment: FAQs: (1) Use a different delimiter.  (2) Use double quotes for variable expansion to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two phases of processing. Firstly by shell, then by sed.

**Shell**
It depends which quotes (double or signle you use). Between sigle (stron quoting) quotes nothing is interpreted as a special character except signle quote. Between double quotes you can put for example `$SHELL_VARIABLE` which will be expanded to it's value.

**Sed**
You should escape (by `\`) these characters: `$.*[\]^` in your regex and the used delimiter - (in your case `/`) in whole sed command.

So, your command should look like:

```
sed -i 's/export KEY_CONFIG=`$EASY_RSA\/whichopensslcnf $EASY_RSA`/export KEY_CONFIG=\/etc\/openvpn\/easy-rsa\/2.0\/openssl-1.0.0.cnf/g'  /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/vars
```

You can also choose other delimiter which doesn't occur in your sed command. For example `#`.

```
sed -i 's#export KEY_CONFIG=`$EASY_RSA/whichopensslcnf $EASY_RSA`#export KEY_CONFIG=/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/openssl-1.0.0.cnf#g'  /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/vars
```

Comment: Try `echo 'that\'s not going to work'` to see why this does not work. (Single quotes cannot be embedded in a single quoted string.)

Comment: @damgad, When I run it i get: ">" like the command has not finished...
`[root@geek-kb ~]# sed -i "s/export KEY_CONFIG='$EASY_RSA/whichopensslcnf $EASY_RSA'/export KEY_CONFIG=/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/openssl-1.0.0.cnf/g" /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/vars`
>`

Comment: @damgad, unfortunately, it still doesn't work:
`[root@geek-kb ~]# sed -i "s/export KEY_CONFIG='$EASY_RSA\/whichopensslcnf $EASY_RSA'/export KEY_CONFIG=\/etc\/openvpn\/easy-rsa\/2.0\/openssl-1.0.0.cnf/g"  /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/vars
[root@geek-kb ~]# grep /whichopensslcnf /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/vars                  export KEY_CONFIG=`$EASY_RSA/whichopensslcnf $EASY_RSA`
[root@geek-kb ~]#`

Comment: Now I see that you don't want to expand `$EASY_RSA` as a shell variable. You should use the first command I posted. `damgad@damgad-Acer-L:~$ cat lala
export KEY_CONFIG='$EASY_RSA/whichopensslcnf $EASY_RSA'
damgad@damgad-Acer-L:~$ sed -i "s/export KEY_CONFIG='\$EASY_RSA\/whichopensslcnf \$EASY_RSA'/export KEY_CONFIG=\/etc\/openvpn\/easy-rsa\/2.0\/openssl-1.0.0.cnf/g" lala
damgad@damgad-Acer-L:~$ cat lala
export KEY_CONFIG=/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/openssl-1.0.0.cnf`

Comment: @ItaiGanot If it's still doesn't work - Perhaps at the begining and end of `'$EASY_RSA/whichopensslcnf $EASY_RSA'` it is ` and not `'` what you want to match?

Answer (score 0):

You can use different delimiter in **sed** like `: _` to separate the command:-

```
echo "Devavrata/sharma" | sed 's:Devavrath/sharma:shivam:g'
```